# Change actionbar separator

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using [Johan Nilsson](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar/) action bar. I just want to know, is it possible to change the action-bar separator into an image? i.e. I want an image as an action-bar separator instead of some color.